# как задать user_agent? undetected_chromedriver, python

Tags: python, chromedriver

не могу задать юзер агент. не работает, почему?

```
chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_0) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15")
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=chrome_options)
```

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.